# Purescript plugin system

Tags: purescript

Does purescript have something like Haskell's System.Plugins?
I need to create some 'generic interface' (sorry for this, I've been programming in object oriented languages for almost 15 years) that other developers will be able to use just by putting a module file in a plugins directory.

I wonder if it is possible since as far as I know Purescript does not have any metadata carried with types at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance, Haskell's `plugins` package is about dynamic loading of Haskell code. The similar concept in JavaScript is [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) or adding a script element to the DOM.

You can make any type assumption for eval'd code using a foreign import or unsafeCoerce. However, you must take care to ensure that the assumption is correct.

I am not aware of a purescript package oriented around these sorts of plugins. In my estimation there would be too much variability in what a plugin could be to really have a sole package for it.